# convert row into column with asc order in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

```
 SELECT * FROM 
  ( 
    SELECT TEST_NAME, SBNO, VAL
    FROM TABLE1

  ) 
  PIVOT ( 
    MAX(VAL) 
  FOR SBNO in (1 value1, 2 value2, 3 value3 ));
```

**Output:**

[image]

I want to show data in ascending order, like this:

2.3 ,  2.4 , 2.5

but result is

2.3 , 2.5 , 2.4

Answer (score 0):

This would do the trick. I have created a new `SBNO` column, ordering by `test_name` and `value` and then `PIVOT` operator will do the rest.

```
;with cte as (
    select
        test_name
        ,val
        ,'Value' + cast(ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by test_name order by test_name, val) as varchar(5)) as new_SBNO
    from TABLE1
)
select *
from cte
pivot (
    max(val)
    for new_SBNO in (value1, value2, value3)
) pvt
```

Comment: `+` is invalid to concatenate strings in SQL (Oracle also need the `;`  at the end of a statement not at the beginning)

Answer (score 0):

I would do this using conditional aggregation:

```
select test_name,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then val end) as value_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then val end) as value_2,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then val end) as value_3
from (select t1.*,
             row_number() over (partition by test_name order by val asc) as seqnum
      from table1 t1
     ) t1
group by test_name;
```

You could express this with `pivot`.  And in Oracle, `pivot` can even be a bit faster.  I just find conditional aggregation to be more flexible and simpler to implement.